# Create a value lookup list for an enum

Tags: python, object, enums

I would like to add a lookup list in `Enum` as a static variable. The best I could do is

```
class Seed(IntEnum):
    HEARTS = 0
    DIAMONDS = 1
    SPADES = 2
    CLUBS = 3
    @staticmethod
    def value_list():
        Seed.list = [s.value for s in Seed]
```

and then in the code I have to do

```
Seed.value_list()
```

to initialize the variable `list` which in this way is not static but is the same for all the instances. Then I can use

```
Seed.list
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: why not just return the list comprehension from that function?

Comment: class' instance variable is NOT used in class' static context. With `Seed.list` you are just creating another static variable

Comment: @Sayse Because I would not like to compute every time I call the function

Comment: @MaPo Then cache it inside the method.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a class [decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator):

```
def values_list(enum_cls):
    # create the values_list attribute and then return the class
    enum_cls.values_list = [member.value for member in enum_cls]
    return enum_cls

@values_list
class Seed(IntEnum):
    HEARTS = 0
    DIAMONDS = 1
    SPADES = 2
    CLUBS = 3

print(Seed.values_list)
# [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: that indeed works around the `IntEnum` limitation that class members must be `int`

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the list of values:

```
from enum import IntEnum


class Seed(IntEnum):
    HEARTS = 0
    DIAMONDS = 1
    SPADES = 2
    CLUBS = 3

    @classmethod
    def values(cls):
        return [s.value for s in cls]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(Seed.values())
```

#### output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: But in this way the list i created every time I call the function. It does not seem very efficient, since it is always  the same

Comment: How often will you call it? The overhead of building a list of 4 values is minimal.